# DBeaver for Snowflake - Display active role?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

Is there option in the toolbar or somewhere else to display the current role you're using in Snowflake ?  I haven't been able to find anything except on the connection window.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find one, and the connection window will show the initial role not the current role.

```
use role accountadmin;
-- The DBeaver connection still shows SYSADMIN. 
-- The current_role() function shows the one in use.
select current_role();
```